# Sending HTTPS requests to REAL-TIME DB using AT COMMANDS and ESP8266

Tags: ssl, firebase-realtime-database, https, esp8266, at-command

In our project we send **HTTPS** requests to **Realtime DB** (in order to add data to it), using the **ESP8266 Wi-Fi component** and **AT commands**.

For months we were able to communicate with Firebase, but last week the communication failed in the `AT+CIPSTART` phase.
We have been trying to find the solution for the problem for a week without success. We would greatly appreciate any help!

**Order of commands:**

> AT+CWMODE=1
> AT+CWJAP="NETWORK_NAME","PASSWORD" 
> AT+CIPSSLSIZE=4096
> AT+CIPSTART="SSL","project-name-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",443
> -----THE ERROR IS HERE-----

**The error:**

> ERROR
> CLOSED

Note: We were able to write a **TCP** message to another site,but for Firebase we need to use **SSL**